# Chazzan forgot to say Tachanun during mincha - how to proceed?

Tags: mistakes, chazzan-prayer-leader, tachanun, mincha-afternoon-prayer

While at shul for mincha the other day, the chazzan began to say Kaddish after finishing *Chazarat Hashat"z' (Shemoneh Esreh repetition). Ata bout the point people answered *Yehei Shmei Rabba*, people yelled at him - "You forgot to say Tachanun!"

The Chazzan answered - "I forgot. Too late, now" and continued with the rest of Kaddish and no one said Tachanun.

What should be done in such a situation?

- Continue Kaddish without Tachanun, as we had done?
- Finish Kaddish, then say Tachanun then *aleinu* without repeating Kaddish?
- Stop Kaddish in the middle, say Tachanun and repeat Kaddish, then Aleinu?

Other factors to consider:

- Someone had told me that if you say Mincha past a certain time when it is close to nightfall (I'm not sure exactly what the break point is - I guess about 10 minutes before *tzet*?) then you wouldn't say Tachanun, anyway?
- Does it matter how much of Kaddish had already been said to decide if to go back to say Tachanun or not?